# How to change bash script output when the script is running?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have the following loop which counts from 0 till 99:

```
    #!/bin/bash

for ((i=0;i<100;i++));
do
   echo $i
   sleep 1
done
```

Is there a way to change the result of the output from terminal while this loop script is running. Lets say if I press letter k the loop automatically add 10 more number to the current number, so if we have 10 being displayed on the screen and we press K the loop should automatically change to 20!
Thanks

Comment: You could look at `trap` to trap certain signals or reading user input ( `read` command ) in your script and modify your script to act according to the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comment you can use:

```
read -t 1 -n 1 key
```

which because of `-t` option we can remove `sleep`, so your script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do
    read -t 1 -n 1 key
    if [ "$key" = "k" ]; then
        i=$((i + 10))
    fi
    echo $i
done
```

But I think more portable could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -t 0 ]; then stty -echo -icanon -icrnl time 0 min 0; fi

keystroke=''
i=0
while [ $i -lt 100 ]; do
    keystroke="$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)" # http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/
    if [ "$keystroke" = "k" ]; then
        i=$(( i + 10 ))
    elif [ "$keystroke" = "q" ]; then
        break
    fi
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
        echo $i
    sleep 1 
done

if [ -t 0 ]; then stty sane; fi

exit 0
```